# How to cite with '&' not 'and' eg. (Lada & Lada 2003) in biblatex

Tags: date, reference, latex, author, biblatex

I'm trying to use & not 'and' in multiple author in-text citation. I wasnt (Lada & Lada, 2003). I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5in, 9.5in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\MakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
     \usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic,citestyle=authoryear,natbib=true,maxnames=2,uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `\finalnamedelim` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5in, 9.5in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\MakeAutoQuote{‘}{’}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
     \usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic,citestyle=authoryear,natbib=true,maxnames=2,uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
        \addspace\&\addspace%
}

\begin{document}


\cite{baez/article}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```